# How to check if one list element contains the substring of the other list element

Tags: python-3.x

I have to take first list element and check if that substring is present in the other list element.
if the substring is present then append that string to another list.

INPUT
list1 = ["2044","1222"]
list2 = ["I am Raman 2044","I am Raman 2044"x,"I am Raman 2044","I am Rohan 1222","I am Rohan 1222"]

OUTPUT
list3 = ["I am Raman 2044I am Raman 2044I am Raman 2044","I am Rohan 1222I am Rohan 1222"]

Comment: The x is typed wrongly, pls ignore that.

Comment: So what have you tried? What is your approach going to be?

Answer (score 1):

to check if string is in a list you use  `a in list[]` in your case, you can use it in loop.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] in list2:
       list2.append(list1[i])
```

Comment: It will not work. I have to check if the substring of list1 is in the list2. If the substring is present then take the element from list2 and append it in the list one.

Comment: not in list one it should be appended in list 3